# How to rewrite database content in html page before loading a page using asp.net webservices

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web-services, meta-tags

I am developing an e-commerce website using C# in ASP.NET with the use of web services, i am calling the data through web services
and setting its value in HTML content, we are also setting the value of meta title and 
meta tags dynamically but when we are trying to see the sources code of HTML page in browser using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> key then its value is not showing.

Comment: Can you show some code examples?

Comment: It depends what you mean by getting them dynamically. If you are getting them through jQuery on the client, then it won't appear in the actual HTML since jQuery is modifying the DOM, not the HTML that is sent to the browser. You need to ensure that the server is the one calling the web service and the HTML and meta tags are rendered from the server, not the client, in order to have the content rendered in the HTML

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion